# Android Coursor out of bounds

Tags: java, android

The code was working good ,than i have added 2 more records to the database and it started to make problems.
Here is my code:

```
 //Workout Name Decider
    public String Workout_Name(String id_S) {
        String workout_name = "";
        String template = "";
        String holder = "";

        if (id_S.equals("REST")) {
            workout_name = "Rest";
        } else {
            String[] allColumns = new String[]{
                    Dbhelper.WORKOUTS_ID,
                    Dbhelper.WORKOUT_NAME,
                    Dbhelper.WORKOUT_TIME

            };
            Cursor cursor = database.query(Dbhelper.TABLE_WORKOUTS_STOCK, allColumns, "_id=\'" + id_S + "\'", null, null, null, null, "1");

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                //id = cursor.getString(2);

                if (cursor.getString(1).contains("SPARTAN SPECIALE ADVANCED") || cursor.getString(1).contains("SPARTAN SPECIALE BEGINNER") || cursor.getString(1).contains("TRICEPS SMASHER REPS")) {
                    template = "(reps)";
                } else {
                    template = "(" + cursor.getString(2) + ")";
                }

            }


            try {
                workout_name_shortener = cursor.getString(1).split("\\s+");
            } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
            }

            int counter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < workout_name_shortener.length; i++) {

                if (workout_name_shortener[i].equals("TIMER") || workout_name_shortener[i].equals("REPS") || workout_name_shortener[i].equals("ADVANCED") || workout_name_shortener[i].equals("BEGINNER") && counter != 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    holder += workout_name_shortener[i] + " ";
                }

                counter++;
            }

            workout_name = holder + template;


            cursor.close();
        }


        return workout_name;
    }
```

And here is the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.spartanbodyweightworkouts, PID: 9198
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.spartanbodyweightworkouts/com.spartanbodyweightworkouts.tabs.plan.planAdapter.planAdapter.PlanAdapter}:
>   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0
>   requested, with a size of 0.....

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement to this:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
  //id = cursor.getString(2);
  if (cursor.getString(1).contains("SPARTAN SPECIALE ADVANCED") || cursor.getString(1).contains("SPARTAN SPECIALE BEGINNER") || cursor.getString(1).contains("TRICEPS SMASHER REPS")) {
    template = "(reps)";
  } else {
    template = "(" + cursor.getString(2) + ")";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the code above is working ,the problem was in my database.I have not closed a record and it was mixing them.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working ,i made an mistake while putting data in the table.